# Points to Centimeter Conversion differs in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

The following code targets a chart's height, in points, and converts it to centimeters.

```
double hvPoints = activeChart.ChartArea.Height; //Returns 211 points
hvCentimeters = hvPoints / (activeChart.Application.CentimetersToPoints(hvPoints / hvPoints)); //Returns 7.44 CM
```

However, the result of 7.44 cm differs quite significantly from the height given in the formatting menu of 7.62 cm. What am I missing?

Thanks, Fredrik

Comment: `hvPoints / hvPoints` will always be `1`. You should write `activeChart.Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)` fro better readability. According to the documentation _1 Point = 0.035cm_. So the better formula would be `hvCentimeters = hvPoints * 0.035` where for enhanced readability `0.035` should be a constant e.g. `centimeterUnit`. Anyway the result will be even less than _7.44cm_.

Comment: I guess you are accessing the wrong object's dimension properties. `ChartArea` contains axes, legends, titles and `PlotArea`. The `ChartArea` itself is part of the `ChartObject`. Maybe the height of _7.62 cm_  refers to `ChartObject.Height` which includes the `ChartArea` and additional elements and layout attributes like margins?

Comment: Yes @BionicCode, spot on. Ended up using chart.parent to access the ChartObject. Thanks for the help.